# Finding a faster way of checking characters in js

Tags: javascript, input, output

I'm trying to make something that gives an output based on your input. I would like it to take every letter and produce something with the next letter in the alphabet. So if I entered "Hello" it would produce "Ifmmp". The only way I can think to do this is with a series of ifs and else ifs, but I would like to know if there is a faster way.

Comment: I'm not necessarily stuck. I just would like to know if there is a faster way of checking characters in a value and changing them accordingly instead of using if (x == 'a') ... else if (x == 'b')...

Comment: Take a look at the ascii table: https://www.asciitable.com/. You might find  some inspiration there :)

Comment: Actually it's a lot easier than using ifs. Start by looking at [String#charCodeAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt), and [String.fromCharCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `String.fromCharCode` feature. For example:

```
let myChar = 'c';
let nextChar = String.fromCharCode(myChar.charCodeAt(0)+1);
console.log(nextChar) // 'd'
```

In your case, you would replace 'c' with your character variable.